# Programmatically clear the state of airflow task instances

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to clear the tasks in DAG B when DAG A **completes execution**. Both A and B are **scheduled** DAGs.

Is there any `operator`/way to clear the state of tasks and re-run DAG B programmatically?

---

I'm aware of the [CLI option](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#clear) and Web UI option to clear the tasks.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend staying away from CLI here!

The airflow functionality of dags/tasks are much better exposed when referencing the objects, as compared to going through BashOperator and/or CLI module.

Add a python operation to **dag A** named "clear_dag_b", that imports dag_b from the **dags** folder(module) and this:

```
from dags.dag_b import dag as dag_b

def clear_dag_b(**context):
   exec_date = context[some date object, I forget the name]
   dag_b.clear(start_date=exec_date, end_date=exec_date)
```

**Important!** If you for some reason do not **match** or **overlap** the dag_b schedule time with start_date/end_date, the clear() operation will miss the dag executions. This example assumes dag **A** and **B** are scheduled identical, and that you only want to clear day **X** from **B**, when **A** executes day **X**

It might make sense to include a check for whether the dag_b has already run or not, before clearing:

```
dab_b_run = dag_b.get_dagrun(exec_date) # returns None or a dag_run object
```

Answer (score 2):

- [`cli.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py) is an incredibly useful place to peep into `SQLAlchemy` magic of `Airflow`.
- The [`clear`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py#L2271) command is implemented [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py#L765)

> ```
> @cli_utils.action_logging
> def clear(args):
>     logging.basicConfig(
>         level=settings.LOGGING_LEVEL,
>         format=settings.SIMPLE_LOG_FORMAT)
>     dags = get_dags(args)
>
>     if args.task_regex:
>         for idx, dag in enumerate(dags):
>             dags[idx] = dag.sub_dag(
>                 task_regex=args.task_regex,
>                 include_downstream=args.downstream,
>                 include_upstream=args.upstream)
>
>     DAG.clear_dags(
>         dags,
>         start_date=args.start_date,
>         end_date=args.end_date,
>         only_failed=args.only_failed,
>         only_running=args.only_running,
>         confirm_prompt=not args.no_confirm,
>         include_subdags=not args.exclude_subdags,
>         include_parentdag=not args.exclude_parentdag,
>     )
> ```

- Looking at the source, you can either

  - replicate it (assuming you also want to modify the functionality a bit)
  - or maybe just do `from airflow.bin import cli` and invoke the required functions directly

Comment: this works better especially when you need to use those flags available in the cli, like `downstream`

Comment: Links to the source file are broken, here is the working link https://github.com/databricks/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py

Answer (score 2):

Since my objective was to re-run the DAG B whenever DAG A completes execution, i ended up clearing the DAG B using BashOperator:

```
# Clear the tasks in another dag
last_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='last_task',
    bash_command= 'airflow clear example_target_dag -c ',
    dag=dag)

first_task >> last_task
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but I would be careful about getting into an endless loop of retries if the task never succeeds. You can call a bash command within the on_retry_callback where you can specify which tasks/dag runs you want to clear.

This works in 2.0 as the [clear](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#clear) commands have changed

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#clear

In this example, I am clearing from t2 & downstream tasks when t3 eventually fails:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def clear_upstream_task(context):
    execution_date = context.get("execution_date")
    clear_tasks = BashOperator(
        task_id='clear_tasks',
        bash_command=f'airflow tasks clear -s {execution_date}  -t t2 -d -y clear_upstream_task'
    )
    return clear_tasks.execute(context=context)


# Default settings applied to all tasks
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5)
}


with DAG('clear_upstream_task',
         start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
         max_active_runs=3,
         schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5),
         default_args=default_args,
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:
    t0 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='t0'
    )

    t1 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='t1'
    )

    t2 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='t2'
    )
    t3 = BashOperator(
        task_id='t3',
        bash_command='exit 123',
        #retries=1,
        on_failure_callback=clear_upstream_task
    )

    t0 >> t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

Comment: whether any REST api way?